# Why does the .Net core template app with docker support not respond at the ip address created by docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm using the add docker support option in .NET Core and I have the following auto-generated launchSettings:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:49800",
      "sslPort": 44327
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the following is the `docker-compose.override.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapplication1:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44327
    ports:
      - "49800:80"
      - "44327:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Docker is automatically opening an ip address it created at https://172.20.167.220/ and it times out.

The top of dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 49800
EXPOSE 44327
EXPOSE 443 #I added this line as an experiment
```

I'm not sure what ip address and port are actually being used because the launchSettings.json does not have a "docker" profile yet the only way to launch the app is by selecting Docker from the debug play button. This app was created by the docker mvc core template. This calls CreateDefaultBuilder in Program.cs so Kestrel is running on localhost:5000/50001 which I assume is mapped to the ports 49800 and 44327 by the iisintegration created by default builder which then should be mapped to ports 80 and 443 by docker on some non-standard ip address that then opens. Am I supposed to open a firewall port in docker?

I suspect I may have done something wrong here where I hard coded the security certificate in `Program.cs`:

```
   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args ) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseKestrel(options=>
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps(@"C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https\WebApplication1.pfx", "bede5cf6-6b63-427a-8576-d3a137f51070");
                });
            }
```

### )

I connected to the container and something in docker settings is not right, as nothing is listening on port 443 when running netstat and the intermediary iis does not appear to be running either on 49800/44327. :

```
C:\app>netstat -a -b -n -o

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4960
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4022           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9804
 [msvsmon.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9192
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11208
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       10080
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3884
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8892
 [dotnet.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5001         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8892
 [dotnet.exe]
  TCP    172.20.170.223:4022    172.20.160.1:54632     ESTABLISHED     5472
 [msvsmon.exe]
  TCP    172.20.170.223:49421   64.4.54.254:443        TIME_WAIT       0
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       4960
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:4022              [::]:0                 LISTENING       9804
 [msvsmon.exe]
  TCP    [::]:5985              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:47001             [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49152             [::]:0                 LISTENING       9192
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49153             [::]:0                 LISTENING       11208
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49154             [::]:0                 LISTENING       10080
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49155             [::]:0                 LISTENING       3884
 [lsass.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5353           *:*                                    10676
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                                    10676
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5353              *:*                                    10676
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                                    10676
 [svchost.exe]
```

Comment: 1. launchSettings.json is only for IDEs. its not used by the ASP.NET Core application itself. 2. Are you running it as administrator? Listening on low port numbers require administrative permissions. Or add per user exceptions netsh.

Comment: @Tseng running what as administrator? Docker/VS/dot net cli? Thanks for your response. I have changed no settings, I just created the app and ran it+added the lines for the certificate in options.listen because otherwise I get a Runtime error about the cert

Comment: Whatever runs docker, be it VS or Powershell :P But your port bindings seem wrong too. You have "49800:80" and "44327:443". on linux too, ports < 1024 are provileged ports too. Just use high random ports, they are internal to the docker anyways. 44327 and 49800 are your EXTERNAL ports, 80 and 443 the internal ones. When you want to connect to the application inside that server you have to call `https://172.20.167.220:44327/. Look at what ports are running within the container with docker exec and run `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN ` inside the container

Comment: @Tseng I'm running windows on windows. I put 44327 and 49800 in because those were the ports iis "is" connectable from launchSettings.json when I launch with Visual Studio and I thought I mapped them to docker ports 443. Do I need to switch the order maybe?

Comment: @Tseng, I killed docker and VS threw an error that yet ANOTHER port is being used; The connection to 172...:4022 has been lost. Perhaps that's a ws port for debugging, but I don't know anything about that.

Comment: @Tseng I'm doing something wrong with the https, b/c docker support for mvc templates runs without https added.